# Adding drag out functionality to VueDraggable (sortable.js)

Tags: html, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I'm using [VueDraggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable) for clean and easy to work with sorting of some elements. However I want to detect when an element I'm dragging leaves it's parent so that I can execute a function. An example would be a browser like Firefox or Chromes tabs and how they sort when you move them left or right but will rip out if dragged out.

However it's [not supported](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/454) in the library. I don't want to have to include another full package for this and haven't found any good alternatives that work well in Vue2+.

Markup snippet

```
<draggable
  @start="onStart"
  @end="onEnd"
  @sort="onSort">
    <div> 
      element to drag
    </div>
</draggable>
```

So how could i go about doing this in a clean manner?

Comment: Will `evt.draggedContext` not work for you to determine if it left the boundary?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. In vuedraggable and in the 7 dom drag events tehre is no draggedContext. And in vuedraggable the :move property doesn't seem to be fired if i add it to my draggable element so that also wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with using getBoundingClientRect() function and adding a Drag event listener that updates x and y variables.

**TS Snippet**

```
private xPosition: number = 0
private yPosition: number = 0
private eventListener?: any    

public onStart() {
  this.eventListener = this.mousePosition.bind(this)
  document.addEventListener('drag', this.eventListener)
}

public onEnd() {
  document.removeEventListener('drag', this.eventListener)

  const draggableElement = this.$refs.draggableElement as any
  const viewport: DOMRect = draggableElement.$el.getBoundingClientRect()

  if (
    this.yPosition > viewport.bottom ||
    this.xPosition > viewport.right ||
    this.xPosition < viewport.left ||
    this.yPosition < viewport.top)
  ) {
    // execute dropped outside whatever here
  }
}

private mousePosition(event: DragEvent) {
  this.xPosition = event.clientX
  this.yPosition = event.clientY
}
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
<draggable
  ref="draggableElement"
  @start="onStart"
  @end="onEnd">
  <div> drag this </div>
</draggable>
```